# Cannot destructure property 'auth' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: typescript, adonisjs

tengo este error:
`Cannot destructure property 'auth' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`
No se que es lo que lo causa, por lo que busque, algo da como valor `undefined` como valor o posible valor de retorno. Estoy usando `AdonisJs 5` y `TypeScript`. Cabe aclarar que me genera el error en varias partes de mi programa pero no en todas. Es bienvenida y agradecida cualquier ayuda

Error log entero:

```
[1630675267302] WARN (api-gestion/7188 on Viotti-Book): pino.final with prettyPrint does not support flushing
[1630675267309] FATAL (api-gestion/7188 on Viotti-Book): Unexpected exception raised from HTTP ExceptionHandler "report" method
    Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\app\Exceptions\Handler'
    Require stack:
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\ImportAliases.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\assembler\build\src\requireHook\ioc-transformer.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\src\esmRequire.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\require-ts\build\src\Compiler\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\require-ts\build\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\assembler\build\src\requireHook\index.js
    - D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\assembler\build\register.js
    - internal/preload
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
        at ImportAliases.resolve (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\ImportAliases.js:95:23)
        at ImportAliases.resolveAsync (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\ImportAliases.js:113:25)
        at Ioc.import (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:280:42)
        at Ioc.makeAsync (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:391:40)
        at IocResolver.call (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Resolver\index.js:90:62)
        at ExceptionManager.reportError (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\API-Gesti├│n\api-gestion\node_modules\@adonisjs\http-server\build\src\Server\ExceptionManager\index.js:81:37)
```

Mi Controlador:

```
import { HttpContextContract } from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext"
import CuentaCorriente from "App/Models/CuentaCorrienteCliente"

export default class CuentasCorrientesController {
    async cuentas_corrientes_clientes({ params }: HttpContextContract, { auth }) {
        if(auth.isLoggedIn){
            try{
                const cuentas_corrientes = await CuentaCorriente.query()
                .where('id_cliente', params.idCliente).where('id_empresa', auth.user.id_empresa)
                return cuentas_corrientes
            }catch(error){
                return error
            }
        }else{
            return "Debe iniciar sesión..."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un método con la siguiente firma:

```js
async cuentas_corrientes_clientes({ params }: HttpContextContract, { auth }) { ...}
```

Es decir, tienes dos parámetros obligatorios que son dos objetos. Uno necesita tener un atributo params y otro un atributo auth. Pero si uno de los dos parámetros falla, ocurrirá un error:

```js
function ejemplo({ params }, { auth }) {
  console.log(params, auth);
}

//escribe undefined porque ni el string "algo" ni el número 2 tienen los atributos que buscamos.
ejemplo("algo", 2);

let obj = {
  params:[1,2,3],
  auth:'abcdef'
};

//muestra los parámetros 
ejemplo(obj,obj);

try {
  //No puede obtener un atributo de undefined o null
  ejemplo(obj, null);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

try {
  //Si no pasamos un parámetro, su valor es undefined
  ejemplo(obj);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!